# Omission of initial "An-" in nickname

Tags: nicknames

I often see that in nicknames, the initial *An-* is omitted.

> Anthony → Tony
>     Android → Droid
>     Andrew → Drew
>     Annabelle → Bella

- Is my understanding correct? Are there restrictions on when this applies?
- If so, why is *An-* omitted? Is it a morpheme meaning something?
- What other regular rules are there in creating English nicknames?

Comment: I fear that you are over-generalising. Angelo !=> Gelo; Annabel !=>Nabel; Anne!=> Ne

Comment: I found Annabel => Bella. Anne is probably too short to be omitted.

Comment: @sawa Na.‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪

Comment: Although a great many nicknames are formed by shortening the first part of a name (David → Dave; Patricia → Pat, e.g.), there are some formed by dropping the first part of the name instead – but that's not limited to names that begin with _An-_, though it seems to happen often when the first syllable is short and begins with a vowel. I know an Alexandra who goes by Xandra, e.g., there's also Amanda → Mandy, Elizabeth → Liz, Eugene → Gene, etc.). Sometimes it can go either way, too; I've known Abigails who have gone by either Abby or Gail.

Comment: Same for Annabelle, this becomes "Annie" more often than "Bella". And "Android" isn't really a name, so "Droid" for a nickname doesn't count. In other words, from your list of examples only "Anthony -> Tony" survives

Comment: @MrLister I have repeatedly seen advertisements of Android that Clearly says "Droid". It does not matter if it is a person's name, it is a proper noun/name of something.

Answer (score 5):

There are no **regular** rules for nicknames. I have a friend whose legal name is *Andrea*. All of her friends call her *'Drea*. Some *Andrew*s are called *Andy* (actually, most of them are, I'd imagine) and not *'Drew*. There's no rule that says their nicknames have to drop the "An": they just do sometimes. I've known women named *Anita* with the nickname *'Nita*: only the initial "A" is dropped.

The only rule for nicknames that matters is what the person with the nickname thinks about it. I have a friend who's tall and morbidly obese. He calls himself *Tiny Tom*.

The famous overweight pool player *[Minnesota Fats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minnesota_Fats)* was originally called *New York Fats*. That was okay by him. *Fats Waller* (jazz singer and piano player), *Fats Domino* (R&B singer), and *Chubby Checker* (pop singer) had no problems with those nicknames.

Nicknames are generally shortenings of given birth names. Turning a multisyllabic name into a monosyllabic one is usually the goal, e.g., *Percival* often becomes *Percy*, *Elizabeth* becomes *Liz*, or *Beth*, or *Liza*, etc., but it could just as easily become *Tater* or *EG* (if her name is, say, *Elizabeth Gloria*), or *Goldie* if she has blond hair.

The famous French writer *Anatole France* never did have the nickname *'Atole*. He was named *Jacques-Anatole-François Thibault* and changed *François* to *France*, a pen name, not really a nickname.

Comment: I knew a "Tater" in high school, although his "real" name was Bobby, which (as you might have guessed) means his parents named him Robert. Just goes to show how convoluted this can get.

Comment: Anyone who calls me Andy gets thwacked.

Comment: A couple other things you could add to this answer, if you wanted to make it more comprehensive: sometimes names are lengthened (with an extra syllable, generally _-y_, so that _John_ becomes _Johnny_ and _George_ becomes _Georgie_, and sometimes names will get shortened **and** lengthened, e.g.: _Edward → Ed → Eddie_, or _Elizabeth → Beth → Betty_. And then there's nicknames often bestowed on sons named after their fathers, like _Junior_ or _Chip_.

Comment: My brother, Andrew, insists on Andi, with that spelling. I think it looks like a girls name. Andrew Leach, above, seems very particular about being called Andrew. There are no rules for nicknames.

Comment: Chubby Checker has (AFAIK) never had a weight problem. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chubby_Checker he got his stage name from an impression of Fats Domino he did:  Fats->Chubby, Dominoes->Checkers